# Save bootstrap model window open if validation not pass

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I have my jspx page marked up with bootstrap. On my page I have modal fade window that is opened clicking on button. Here is the button:

```
<button id="createTemplate" type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" 
data-target="#dialogCreateTemplate" title="save">Save</button>
```

Button opens window with form input fields. This form is validated by javax validation. This is controller method:

```
    @RequestMapping("/create")
    public String create(Model model, @Valid TemplateForm templateForm, BindingResult bindingResult)
    {
        if (templateForm.getCreateTemplate() == null || bindingResult.hasErrors())
        {
            return "/template/view";
        }
        webService.createTemplate(templateForm.getTemplate());
        return "/template/search";
    }
```

The problem is: when some errors take place, my controller returns page with closed modal window and I can see error messages only if I blick button, that opens modal window. How to prevent closing the dialog? Or return page with already opened dialog?